# Open with DW adds folder/files to .svn folder

Tags: svn, dreamweaver

When I open SVN working folder with Dreamweaver, it creates additional folder and files.

[image]

Do I have to commit it to the SVN or don't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are files used by SVN for administration. See here for more explanation http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch08s03.html - Those are not extra files by dreamweaver, but are created by subversion for tracking and administration.(These of course need not be explicitly committed).

By default you would not even see the option to commit on these files (via tortoiseSVN, or even commandline client).

Answer (score 1):

I think just commit the changes only. If u have spare time, u can find more about the files (what they're for) or compare them with the previous version (if exists). Some svn usually output files when doing checkout.
Thanks.